# Exclude particular property from validation. FluentValidation

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, fluentvalidation, modelstate

I have a class with complex property:

```
public class A{
    public B Property{ get; set; }
}

public class B{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

In some cases I'm using only B type, in others A type. But I want to validate B type itself but NOT validate B type as part of A class.

I wrote those validators:

```
public class BValidator : AbstractValidator<B>
{
    public BValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty();
    }
}
public class AValidator : AbstractValidator<A>
{
    public BValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.A).Configure(x => x.ClearValidators());
    }
}
```

And it works inside my views. But when I post A class with empty B.Name the ModelState is not valid. Is it the way to make ModelState valid?

Answer (score 0):

"B" "a part of A" is not going to run unless you tell it to.

B validation **as a part of A**........is only going to happen if you ask it to.

Below I've made "B as a part of A" as optional, via a bool flag to demonstrate.

```
public class AValidator : AbstractValidator<A>
{
    public AValidator (bool includeBasAPartOfA)
    {

           if(includeBasAPartOfA)
           {
                    RuleFor(x => x.Property).SetValidator(new BValidator());
           }

    }
}
```